# iTunes RSS Feed returning max. 100 items instead of 300

Tags: rss, itunes

I tried the iTunes RSS generator at http://itunes.apple.com/rss/generator/ to download the newest 300 games, which gave me the RSS Feed URL http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/newapplications/limit=300/genre=6014/xml.

However, only 100 are returned, and alphabetically sorted, so the list stops at the letter E ...

Did Apple restrict the amount of items one could get without updating their RSS Feed Generator? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you missed something, I have now tried it and I have the same problem. Maybe is a problem of the Apple site, or maybe the browser cannot manage 300 values of a rss feed.

Comment: Well, I tried an RSS reader too, and it only returns 100 ... pretty useless like that, 100 new apps are in the store within a few hours ...

Comment: Yeah..very useless. Maybe we should ask to Mr. Jobs to solve this problem!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah, it's fairly broken.

to get more data you can sign up for the enterprise data feed program.  it ain't pretty.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html

Answer (score 1):

This is disappointing, but it is documented here:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---rss-feed-generator.html

'The "New Apps," "New Free Applications, and "New Paid Applications" feeds, for the "Apps" media type are not customizable for genre or number of results.'