# iTunes Customer Reviews RSS Feed stops at page 10

Tags: rss, itunes

I'm trying to programmatically fetch reviews from the iTunes store for a particular app. Like so:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=380293530/sortBy=mostRecent/xml

This works great, and the XML even has built in pagination telling me where's the next page is.

However, the last page that it will load is page 10. Everything afterwards (e.g. [page 11](http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/page=11/id=380293530/sortby=mostrecent/xml?cc=us)) return bad gateway. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: if only 10 pages were actually 10 pages - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518593/itunes-rss-feed-returning-max-100-items-instead-of-300

Answer (score 4):

Yes the iTunes Review RSS feed only goes up to page 10. We initially thought this was a bug, and filed a Radar. Apple closed it as "Works as intended".

So... you have to grab 10 pages, database each review with an ID, then store going forward to build up a longer history.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes shows only maximum of 10 pages, so their (private) RSS API supports up to 10 pages.